# CSS: How to move-up #thumbnails between #header and #content with CSS (no JavaScript,dynamic width and height,not changing HTML)?

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser

How to move-up `#thumbnails` between `#header` and `#content` with CSS (no JavaScript), without changing HTML and keeping dynamic width and height for all div tags?
Code able in http://jsfiddle.net/laukstein/XdJxu/

HTML:

```
<div id=container>
    <div id=header>1. header</div>
    <div id=content>3. content</div>
    <div id=thumbnails>2. thumbnails</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body,* html #container{height:100%;}
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:inherit;
}
#container{
    width:80%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
#content{
    background-color:#ececec;
}
#thumbnails{
    background-color:#ffdc71;
}
```

**Expected result** (cross-browser, dynamic width and height, no JS, no HTML changes):

```
    1. header
    2. thumbnails
    3. content
```

Comment: Any particular reason why no JS? This can't be done without JS and have dynamic height...

Comment: @Myles Gray: I'll like searching engines and browsers without JS support render it 1, 2, 3. And dynamic width and height I need for [responsive web design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

Comment: It would be nice but doing this with CSS is simply not possible, you HAVE to use JS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XdJxu/1/)**

Rather dirty as it isn't dynamic height but it is a proof of concept,
All i did was add:

```
#content{
    margin-top:15px;
}
#thumbnails{
    margin-top:-35px;
}
```

**[Live Demo with JS](http://jsfiddle.net/XdJxu/4/)** - No JQuery now. Thanks to @AndyE for non JQ version

Comment: Thanks for your post! Seems like still there are no just CSS (without JS) issue for that. I updated http://jsfiddle.net/laukstein/XdJxu/5/ on using jQuery `$('#header').after($('#thumbnails'));`. `.after()` has better speed performance then `.insertAfter()` http://jsperf.com/after-vs-insertafter

Comment: @Binyamin - Check http://jsfiddle.net/XdJxu/4/ it uses NO JQuery, this is bound to be faster than a JQuery solution.

Comment: I updated http://jsperf.com/after-vs-insertafter . You are right, your example with `parentNode.insertBefore()` is even faster then jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be done without knowing the height of #thumbnails, since that's the amount of pixels you have to "move" #content downwards (either through positioning or margin-top).